# Issue with Disappearing Characters Every Second Position After Encryption and Decryption in RSA

Tags: javascript, encryption, rsa

I am currently facing an issue with my RSA encryption and decryption process. After encrypting and decrypting a message, I noticed that every second character in the decrypted message is disappearing. I have carefully reviewed my code and even reverted to the original implementation, but the problem persists.

Here is a summary of my code:

```js
function gcd(a, b) {
    while (b !== 0) {
        const temp = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = temp;
    }
    return a;
}

function modInverse(a, n) {
    let [old_r, r] = [a, n];
    let [old_s, s] = [1n, 0n];

    while (r !== 0n) {
        const quotient = old_r / r;
        [old_r, r] = [r, old_r - quotient * r];
        [old_s, s] = [s, old_s - quotient * s];
    }

    if (old_r !== 1n) {
        throw new Error("No modular inverse exists");
    }

    return (old_s + n) % n;
}


function stringToPrimes(inputString) {
    let hash = 0n;

    for (let i = 0; i < inputString.length; i++) {
        const codePoint = inputString.codePointAt(i);
        hash = (hash * 31n + BigInt(codePoint)) % (2n ** 31n - 1n);
    }

    const p = nextPrime(hash);
    const q = nextPrime(p + 1n);

    return [p, q];
}


function nextPrime(n) {
    while (!isPrime(n)) {
        n++;
    }
    return n;
}


function isPrime(n) {
    if (n <= 1n) return false;
    if (n <= 3n) return true;
    if (n % 2n === 0n || n % 3n === 0n) return false;

    let i = 5n;
    while (i * i <= n) {
        if (n % i === 0n || n % (i + 2n) === 0n) return false;
        i += 6n;
    }

    return true;
}


function generateRSAKeyPair(p, q) {
    const N = p * q;
    const totient = (p - 1n) * (q - 1n);
    const e = 65537n; 
    const d = modInverse(e, totient);

    return {
        publicKey: { N, e },
        privateKey: { N, d }
    };
}


function signMessage(message, privateKey) {
    const { N, d } = privateKey;
    const signature = modPow(message, d, N);
    return signature;
}


function verifySignature(signature, publicKey) {
    const { N, e } = publicKey;
    const message = modPow(signature, e, N);
    return message;
}


function modPow(a, b, m) {
    let result = 1n;
    a = a % m;

    while (b > 0n) {
        if (b % 2n === 1n) {
            result = (result * BigInt(a)) % m;
        }

        b = b >> 1n;
        a = (BigInt(a) * BigInt(a)) % m;
    }

    return result;
}

function bigIntToString(value) {
    let result = '';
    let current = value;

    while (current > 0n) {
        const charCode = Number(current & 255n);
        result = String.fromCharCode(charCode) + result;
        current = BigInt(current) >> 8n;  
    }

    return result;
}

function stringToBigInt(str) {
    let result = 0n;
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        const codePoint = str.codePointAt(i);
        const codePointSize = codePoint > 0xFFFF ? 4 : 2; 
        result = result * (2n ** BigInt(8 * codePointSize)) + BigInt(codePoint);
        i += codePointSize - 1; 
    }
    return result;
}

const userInput = "Hello, World!!!Gen Password!!!!";

const [p, q] = stringToPrimes(userInput);

const keyPair = generateRSAKeyPair(p, q);
console.log("Generated RSA Key Pair:", keyPair);

const message = stringToBigInt('1234567');
const signature = signMessage(message, keyPair.privateKey);
console.log("Message:", message);
console.log("Signature:", signature);


const verifiedMessage = verifySignature(signature, keyPair.publicKey);
console.log("Verified Message:",verifiedMessage, bigIntToString(verifiedMessage));
console.log( bigIntToString(verifiedMessage) );
```

See, as the message is [1234567], it's result come out as [1 3 5 7 ]

And, when the message string exceeds 7 characters. I get non-alphabetical output

Comment: check what `codePointSize` is in `stringToBigInt` - you may be doing some weird stuff in that loop

Comment: `i += codePointSize - 1;` <-- This causes `i += 2` because you already have `i++` in your `for` statement - but I don't know RSA well enough to say if this is correct or not - because when I remove the offending line I get non-alphabetical output.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Ax4Xc26e seems to work

Comment: Thanks for helping, I've encountered an issue when the message string exceeds 7 characters. An error occurs. Do you have any suggestions on how to resolve this?"

Comment: `stringToBigInt` doesn't uniquely encode a string, and `stringToBigInt` and `bigIntToString` clearly aren't inverses of each other.

Comment: @KaFong Whenever you are trying to convey an error, please indicate the exact error you're getting.

Comment: the error from my browser, i see thay normal JS cannot cal more than 15digits

Comment: When converting between string and BigInt, you could first create a typed array as an intermediate step, e.g. with `new TextEncoder().encode()`, and then convert the typed array to BigInt, e.g. as here: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/SMb. Note [this hint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#cryptography) for the use of BigInt in the context of cryptography (for a toy application, however, this is not critical).